# Homogeneous polynomial

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, harmonic-functions

Can a homogeneous harmonic polynomial mapping $p(x)=(p_1(x),p_2(x),p_3(x))$, $p(0)=0$, of odd degree $m\ge 3$, of the unit ball $B^3$ into $R^3$ be injective. This means that $p_i$ are harmonic polynomials and $p_i(tx)=t^m p_i(x)$ for every $i$.

Comment: Try restricting to a sphere (so you have a triple of spherical functions), and projecting the output to a sphere.

Comment: It is a hard staff S. Carnahan...